# How would I go about deleting a sprite?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

**So the problem is an trying to get my sprite to disappear once the health bar goes 0 but I can’t seem to that the most I can do is make him invisible but I am trying to delete my sprite not make it  invisible**

```
import pygame import sys

pygame.init()#We always need to initalize our pygame IN EVERY PROJECT/FILE

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 480))# Here win is representing "window" for our screen which we have set at 500 by 480

pygame.display.set_caption("Dragon Ball Z Mini-game")#We are giving our Window/Screen a name

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_right_image0 - t.png'), pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_right_image1 - t.png'), pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_right_image2 - t.png'), pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_right_image3 - t.png'), pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_right_image4 - t.png')] walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_left_image0 - t.png'), pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_left_image1 - t.png'), pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_left_image2 - t.png'), pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_left_image3 - t.png'), pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_left_image4 - t.png')] bg = pygame.image.load('image/bg2.jpg') char = pygame.image.load('image/young_goku - standing - t.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bulletSound = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/kiblast.wav") hitSound = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/Bomb+1.wav")
#bulletSound.play() music = pygame.mixer.music.load("image/Dragon Ball Z - Rock The Dragon.mp3") pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

score = 0

class player(object): def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.vel = 5
    self.isJump = False
    self.left = False
    self.right = False
    self.walkCount = 0
    self.jumpCount = 10
    self.standing = True
    self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)

def draw(self, win):
    font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("Papyrus", 45)
    text2 = font2.render("DBZ Adventure!", 1, (255, 50, 25))
    win.blit(text2, (120 - (text2.get_width() / 2), 15))
    #pygame.display.flip()
    if self.walkCount + 1 >= 10:
        self.walkCount = 0
    if not (self.standing):
        if self.left:
            win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
    else:
        if self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
        else:
            win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
    self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        if self.left:
            ki_stance_left = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki_left.png")
            win.blit(ki_stance_left, (self.x, self.y))

        elif self.right:
            ki_stance = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki.png")
            win.blit(ki_stance, (self.x, self.y))

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if self.left:#needed to put self.left and self the right
            ki_stance_left = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki_left.png")
            win.blit(ki_stance_left, (self.x, self.y))

        elif self.right:
            ki_stance = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki.png")
            win.blit(ki_stance, (self.x, self.y))

            pygame.display.flip()

def hit(self):
    self.isJump = False
    self.jumpCount = 10
    self.x = 100
    self.y = 410
    self.walkCount = 0
    font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 100)
    text = font1.render('-5', 1, (255, 0, 0))
    win.blit(text, (250 - (text.get_width() / 2), 200))
    pygame.display.update()
    i = 0
    while i < 200:
        pygame.time.delay(10)
        i += 1
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                i = 201
                pygame.quit()


class projectile(object): def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.radius = radius
    self.color = color
    self.facing = facing
    self.vel = 8 * facing

def draw(self, win):
    ki = pygame.image.load("image/ki.png")
    win.blit(ki, (self.x, self.y))
    ki_stance = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki.png")
    win.blit(ki, (self.x, self.y))
    pygame.draw.circle(win, (255,255,0), (self.x, self.y), self.radius) """ def draw2(self, win):
    ki2 = pygame.image.load("image/b4.png")
    win.blit(ki2, (self.x, self.y))
    ki_stance = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki.png")
    win.blit(ki2, (self.x, self.y))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 0), (self.x, self.y), self.radius) """

class projectile2(): def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.radius = radius
    self.color = color
    self.facing = facing
    self.vel = 8 * facing

def draw(self, win):
    ki = pygame.image.load("image/b4.png")
    win.blit(ki, (self.x, self.y))
    ki_stance = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki.png")
    win.blit(ki, (self.x, self.y))
    #pygame.draw.circle(win, (0,0,139), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)








class enemy(object): walkRight = [pygame.image.load("image/R1E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R2E.png"),
             pygame.image.load("image/R3E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R4E.png"),
             pygame.image.load("image/R5E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R6E.png"),
             pygame.image.load("image/R7E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R8E.png"),
             pygame.image.load("image/R9E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R10E.png"),
             pygame.image.load("image/R11E.png")] walkLeft = [pygame.image.load("image/L1E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L2E.png"),
            pygame.image.load("image/L3E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L4E.png"),
            pygame.image.load("image/L5E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L6E.png"),
            pygame.image.load("image/L7E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L8E.png"),
            pygame.image.load("image/L9E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L10E.png"),
            pygame.image.load("image/L11E.png")]

def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.end = end
    self.path = [self.x, self.end]
    self.walkCount = 0
    self.vel = 3
    self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
    self.health = 10
    self.visible = True

def draw(self, win):
    self.move()
    if self.visible:
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 33:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.vel > 0:
            win.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            win.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1

        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 128, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
        # pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)

def move(self):
    if self.vel > 0:
        if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
            self.x += self.vel
        else:
            self.vel = self.vel * -1
            self.walkCount = 0
    else:
        if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
            self.x += self.vel
        else:
            self.vel = self.vel * -1
            self.walkCount = 0
```

**Here’s where I can keep on trying to delete my sprite but it does not seem to work?  The most I can do is just make it invisible but it  does not go away permanently.**

```
    def hit(self):
            hit = enemy
            if self.health > 0:
                self.health -= 1


            else:
                self.visible = False
                font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("Papyrus", 45)
                text2 = font2.render("You won!", 5, (45, 50, 45))
                win.blit(text2, (95 - (text2.get_width() / 3), 45))
                pygame.display.flip()
            print('hit')


class enemy2(): walkRight = [pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite-standing-T.gif"), pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite-moving_T.gif"), pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite-moving_T.gif"), pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite-move_right-T.gif")] walkLeft = [pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite-standing-T.gif"), pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite - moving_left-T.gif"), pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite - moving_left-T.gif"), pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite - moving_left2-T.gif")] def
__init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.end = end
    self.path = [self.x, self.end]
    self.walkcount = 0
    self.vel = 3
    self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28, 60)
    self.health = 10
    self.visible = True

def draw(self, win):
    self.move()
    if self.visible:
        if self.walkcount + 0 >= 10:
            self.walkcount = 0

        if self.vel > 0:
            win.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkcount += 1
        else:
            win.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkcount += 1
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 128, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28, 60)

def move(self):
    if self.vel > 0:
        if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
            self.x += self.vel
        else:
            self.vel = self.vel * -1
            self.walkcount = 0

    else:
        if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
            self.x += self.vel
        else:
            self.vel = self.vel * -1
            self.walkcount = 0

def hit(self):
    if self.health > 0:
        self.health -= 1
    else:
        self.visible = False
        self.visible = False
        font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("Papyrus", 45)
        text2 = font2.render("You won!", 5, (45, 50, 45))
        win.blit(text2, (95 - (text2.get_width() / 3), 45))
        pygame.display.flip()

    print("Hit!!")
    pass


def redrawGameWindow(): win.blit(bg, (0, 0)) text = font.render('Score: ' + str(score), 1, (0, 0, 0)) win.blit(text, (390, 5)) man.draw(win) goblin.draw(win) goblin2.draw(win) for bullet in bullets:
    bullet.draw(win)

pygame.display.update()


# mainloop font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 30, True, True) man = player(200, 420, 64, 64) goblin = enemy(50, 410, 64, 64, 450) goblin2 = enemy2(250, 410, 64, 64, 450) shootloop = 0 bullets = [] run
= True while run: clock.tick(27) if goblin.visible == True:
    if man.hitbox[1] < goblin.hitbox[1] + goblin.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > goblin.hitbox[1]:
        if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > goblin.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < goblin.hitbox[0] + goblin.hitbox[2]:
            man.hit()
            score -= 5
            print("Hurt")

if goblin2.visible == True:
    if man.hitbox[1] < goblin2.hitbox[1] + goblin2.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > goblin2.hitbox[1]:
        if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > goblin2.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < goblin2.hitbox[0] + goblin2.hitbox[2]:
            man.hit()
            score -= 5
            print("Hurt")

if shootloop > 0:
    shootloop += 1 if shootloop > 3:
    shootloop = 0

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        #pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
        run = False

for bullet in bullets:
    if bullet.y - bullet.radius < goblin.hitbox[1] + goblin.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > goblin.hitbox[1]:
        if bullet.x + bullet.radius > goblin.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < goblin.hitbox[0] + goblin.hitbox[2]:
            #hitSound.play()
            goblin.hit()
            score += 1
            #bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

for bullet in bullets:
    if bullet.y - bullet.radius < goblin2.hitbox[1] + goblin2.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > goblin2.hitbox[1]:
         if bullet.x + bullet.radius > goblin2.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < goblin2.hitbox[0] + goblin2.hitbox[2]:
            #hitSound.play()
            goblin2.hit()
            score += 1
            #bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
        bullet.x += bullet.vel
    else:
        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and shootloop == 0:
    bulletSound.play()
    if man.left:
        facing = -1
    else:
        facing = 1

    if len(bullets) < 5:
        bullets.append(projectile(round(man.x + man.width // 3), round(man.y + man.height // 3), 6, (0, 0, 0), facing))
    shootloop = 1

if keys[pygame.K_a] and shootloop == 0:
    bulletSound.play()
    if man.left:
        facing = -1
    else:
        facing = 1

    if len(bullets) < 5:
        bullets.append(projectile2(round(man.x + man.width // 3), round(man.y + man.height // 3), 12, (0, 0, 0), facing))
    shootloop = 1

if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
    man.x -= man.vel
    man.left = True
    man.right = False
    man.standing = False elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
    man.x += man.vel
    man.right = True
    man.left = False
    man.standing = False else:
    man.standing = True
    man.walkCount = 0

if not (man.isJump):
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        man.isJump = True
        man.right = False
        man.left = False
        man.walkCount = 0 else:
    if man.jumpCount >= -10:
        neg = 1
        if man.jumpCount < 0:
            neg = -1
        man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
        man.jumpCount -= 1
    else:
        man.isJump = False
        man.jumpCount = 10

redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not display removed sprites, Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474236/do-not-display-removed-sprites-pygame)

Comment: So I have tried that but .Kill or .remove don’t pop up as an option for me?

Comment: Your question is too long. Try to summarize it.

Comment: Please read the part where I am trying to delete my sprite @AlirezaHI  I just put the rest of the code in case that helps in any kind of way

Comment: The reason that you are not seeing `kill()` as an option is that your player, projectile and enemy classes are not subclasses of pygame.Sprite and you are also not using Sprite Groups. You should use those. It will make things simpler.

Comment: You cannot "delete" an image which is drawn of the display Surface. The image is just a bunch of pixels. You have to redraw all the objects in every frame. If you don't need an object any more, then just skip it. If you use [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), then this can be done by [`kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill)

Comment: @Rabbid76 could you show an example please?

Comment: Here is an example of `pygame.sprite.Sprite` and `pygame.sprite.Group`: https://www.101computing.net/creating-sprites-using-pygame/. Once you call a `.kill()` on a sprite, it removes itself from all Groups, and starts returning `False` when you call `.alive()`. Because it is no longer in a Group, it does not get drawn in the cumulative `.draw()` method of the `all_sprites_list`. Then, as it is not part of any Groups, if you did not assign names to the sprites, they vanish for good. If they have individual names, you can call pythons `del` to get rid of them, and then they are gone permanently.

Answer (score -1):

In order to move a created image off of the screen you can do either one of the following solutions.

**1.** Move the image off of the screen.

An example of moving a sprite off of a screen is as follows:

```
someImg = pygame.image.load("coolWater.png") 
screen.blit(someImg, (int(someXValueOffScreen), int(someYValueOffScreen))
```

**2.** Make the image transparent

Here's an example of this:

```
someImg = pygame.image.load("coolWater.png")
someImg.image.fill((0,0,0,0)) #Makes the image transparent. The last parameter is the alpha value. An alpha value of 0 makes it transparent. The first 3 zeros is the RGB value
```

Quick note: You should format your code in this post correctly with encapsulating your code with these three characters " ``` ".